# Viewing PDF documents saved with Word sometimes shows no table borders

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, microsoft-word-2010, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader

Whenever I save a document created with Word **2010** that has tables in it and borders on the table and cells and then open it in Adobe Reader, for some reason some of the cells do not show the borders, for example:

[image]

In **Word**, there is a border above the word "Privacy Policy".

I did some research online and it seems you can *kinda* fix this by changing a setting in Adobe Reader, that being:

Edit -> Preferences -> Page Display (uncheck *Enhance thin lines*)

However that doesn't help me, I want to fix the issue from happening from the stance of **Word**, not apply a bandaid to it in Adobe Reader - I'm not really going to tell everyone I send PDF's to they may have to change this setting now am I!?

So my question is, why does it seem Word is creating borders that aren't equal or saving it as a PDF incorrectly.

Is there a way to fix this in Word so when saving it as a PDF and open it in Adobe Reader all the borders show just like in Word?

Comment: What happens if you zoom in on the PDF? If the lines "magically" appear, then make them thicker in Word before exporting your PDF

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad That does work, however I tried making them thicker before in Word, but for some reason the setting doesn't seem to stick - seems to be stuck on `1/2pt` no matter what I select; which in itself I guess is another problem altogether.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem has to do with how Acrobat renders thin lines. They will appear when you zoom in (they can also be visible at the same zoom % on one screen and not on another)

The solution is to make the strokes of the table thicker:

1) Select the table

2) Select a thicker stroke size (1 pt should be enough):

[image]

3) Apply the border to the table:

[image]

Note that new tables will automatically go back to 1/2 pt strokes.

To change the default behaviour, you need to change the table styles. See [this link](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/change-words-default-table-properties-to-suit-the-way-you-work/) for how

Comment: Thanks for that. Still having trouble getting all my borders to change, tried some of the stuff at that link but then the table seemed to have some even/odd thing going on, but looking at the settings didn't show any difference; but I think you have answered this particular question however :)