# Table borders created in Word are uneven as PDF

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, border, table-styles

I created a table in Word and added a 2 1/4 pt white border. The table also has shading which was applied to the cells. The table looks fine in Word. However, when I save the document as a PDF, the borders appear in PDF with a small notch, as if a portion of the border does not extend far enough alongside the cell.

Screenshot of PDF output:

[image]

I've tried changing the border width, but it makes no difference. With a 3 pt border, I get the same result. All cell margins are the same. "Allow spacing between cells" is NOT checked for any cells.

UPDATE:

In Adobe Acrobat, if I go to Edit > Preferences > Page Display > Rendering and uncheck "Enhance thin lines," the effect almost disappears. Almost.

When I print, it's nearly impossible to see the change in border width. This is a report that will be shared electronically, but at least the print version will be acceptable.

Comment: Post an example document.

Comment: PDF: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=45518934952618646087

Comment: Word version: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=50964328088678390137

Comment: Possible dupe of [Viewing PDF documents saved with Word sometimes shows no table borders - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1370952/viewing-pdf-documents-saved-with-word-sometimes-shows-no-table-borders), and [Microsoft Word - Table Cells with background colour reduce thickness of borders](https://superuser.com/questions/1543931/microsoft-word-table-cells-with-background-colour-reduce-thickness-of-borders)

Comment: @DavidPostill, I tried the solutions in those posts but neither worked. Altering preferences in Adobe did help though. Thank you for the links!

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the top and bottom margins were responsible for the strange uneven borders. I changed the top and bottom cell margins to 0 and added paragraph spacing instead. The notch at the top disappeared completely.

Acknowledgement: [Table Border Challenges Converting Word to PDF](https://stack.payne.run/blog/2013/03/21/table-border-challenges-converting-word-pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Is there a text box in your document either?

I download your example document, when I adjust the text box **bigger**, then the issue goes away.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. How much bigger did you make it? I gave that a try but I get the same effect.